# SSIS - use Error Redirect output in the same package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have one question, I want to use redirected error output file or table in the same package after correcting the error. suppose I have input file which have the bad rows which I get in the redirected error output file/table, then I  will manually correcting all bad records, then when I run the same package it will automatically detect the error record and process the all error records else process normally.

Please suggest some mechanism which can do this thing.

Suggestion and guidance invited.

Regards, 
Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Lookup` to find whether the rows are present in the destination table or not . Suppose there are error rows and 50% of your data got inserted into your destination table from the flat file .Now after the error rows are corrected in the flat file when you again run your package ,the lookup component will only insert the data which does not have any matching in the destination table .

Connect OLEDB destination to your `lookup matched` output and an OLEDB command to your `lookup No Matched Output`

refer this [article1](http://www.ssistalk.com/2009/09/04/ssis-lookup-cache-modes-full-partial-none/) and [arcticle2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/)